# urgently Need in increasing code coverage its 36 % unable to cover if else condition

Tags: unit-test

Controller:

```
public class RFLEET_ProtocolDynamicGrid {

public string Id;
public string selcontactid ;
public String gridtype{get;set;}
public String gridname{get;set;}
public String linename{get;set;}
public String gridid{get;set;}
public boolean showgrid{get; set;}
public boolean showgrid1{get; set;}
public boolean showgrid2{get; set;}
public boolean showgrid3{get; set;}
public boolean showgrid4{get; set;}
public boolean showgrid5{get; set;}
public boolean showgrid6{get; set;}
public boolean showgrid7{get; set;}
public boolean showgrid8{get; set;}
public boolean showsave{get; set;}
public boolean showsave1{get; set;}
public boolean showsave2{get; set;}
public boolean showsave3{get; set;}
public boolean showsave4{get; set;}
public boolean showsave5{get; set;}
public boolean showsave6{get; set;}
public boolean showsave7{get; set;}
public boolean showsave8{get; set;}

public boolean showhide{get; set;}
public boolean selectedval{get; set;}
public Boolean refreshPage {get; set;}
public string mdparamter;
public string Discountparam;
public List<RFLEET_Protocol_Line__c> line1{get;set;}
public List<RFLEET_Protocol_Line__c> con{get;set;}
public List<RFLEET_Protocol_Line__c> allcons {get;set;}
public List<RFLEET_Protocol_Line__c> pro{get;set;}
List<RFLEET_Protocol_Line__c> selectcon{get;set;}
List<RFLEET_Protocol_Line__c> selectcon1{get;set;}
List<RFLEET_Protocol_Line__c> selectcon2{get;set;}
List<RFLEET_Protocol_Line__c> selectcon3{get;set;}
List<RFLEET_Protocol_Line__c> selectcon4{get;set;}
List<RFLEET_Protocol_Line__c> selectcon5{get;set;}
List<RFLEET_Protocol_Line__c> selectcon6{get;set;}
List<RFLEET_Protocol_Line__c> selectcon7{get;set;}
List<RFLEET_Protocol_Line__c> selectcon8{get;set;}

public RFLEET_ProtocolDynamicGrid(ApexPages.StandardController controller) 
{

    id=ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');       
    RFLEET_Protocol_Grid__c grid=[select id,Name,Rfleet_Type_of_Grid__c from RFLEET_Protocol_Grid__c where id=:id];
    gridtype=grid.Rfleet_Type_of_Grid__c;
    gridname=grid.name;
    gridid=grid.id;

    line1=[select Id,Rfleet_Protocol_grid_name__c from RFLEET_Protocol_Line__c where Rfleet_Protocol_grid_name__r.Name=:gridname];

    integer k=line1.size();

    if(line1.size()>0){

        system.debug('>>>>>>>>>>>>success'+k);
        if(gridtype=='Model - Discount %'){getprotocolgrid();}
        else if(gridtype=='Model, Version - Discount %') {getprotocolgrid1();}
        else if(gridtype=='Model, Version, Option - Discount %'){getprotocolgrid2();}
        else if(gridtype=='Model - Discount %, Volume'){getprotocolgrid3();}
        else if(gridtype=='Model, Version - Discount %, Volume'){getprotocolgrid4();}
        else if(gridtype=='Model, Version, Option - Discount %, Volume'){getprotocolgrid5();}
        else if(gridtype=='Model - Unique price, Unique price %,Volume'){getprotocolgrid6();}
        else if(gridtype=='Model, Version - Unique price, Unique price %,Volume'){getprotocolgrid7();}
        else if(gridtype=='Model, Version, Option - Unique price, Unique price %,Volume'){getprotocolgrid8();}
        else{}    
    }
    else{

    system.debug('>>>>>>>>>>>>fail'+k);
    if(gridtype=='Model - Discount %'){displayemptyCol();}
        else if(gridtype=='Model, Version - Discount %') {displayemptyCol1();}
        else if(gridtype=='Model, Version, Option - Discount %'){displayemptyCol2();}
        else if(gridtype=='Model - Discount %, Volume'){displayemptyCol3();}
        else if(gridtype=='Model, Version - Discount %, Volume'){displayemptyCol4();}
        else if(gridtype=='Model, Version, Option - Discount %, Volume'){displayemptyCol5();}
        else if(gridtype=='Model - Unique price, Unique price %,Volume'){displayemptyCol6();}
        else if(gridtype=='Model, Version - Unique price, Unique price %,Volume'){displayemptyCol7();}
        else if(gridtype=='Model, Version, Option - Unique price, Unique price %,Volume'){displayemptyCol8();}
        else{}  
    }
}

public PageReference Selectedval(){
    mdparamter= Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Model1');  
    Discountparam= Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Discount1');
    system.debug('----->model'+mdparamter); 
    system.debug('----->Discount'+Discountparam);
    RFLEET_Protocol_Line__c proline = [Select Rfleet_Model__c,Rfleet_Discount__c from RFLEET_Protocol_Line__c where id=:selcontactid ];      
    proline.Rfleet_Model__c= mdparamter;
    if(Discountparam!=''){
    system.debug('-----withvalue');
    proline.Rfleet_Discount__c= Decimal.valueof(Discountparam);
        }else{ 
     system.debug('-----without');
    proline.Rfleet_Discount__c=0;


    }
    update proline;
    refreshPage=true;  

    return null;
} 

public PageReference Delrecords(){

    RFLEET_Protocol_Line__c proline = [Select id from RFLEET_Protocol_Line__c where id=:selcontactid ];      

    delete proline; 
    refreshPage=true;  
    return null;
} 
Public List<RFLEET_Protocol_Line__c> getprotocolgrid(){
    allcons = [Select Id,Rfleet_Discount__c,Rfleet_Model__c,Rfleet_Protocol_grid_name__c from RFLEET_Protocol_Line__c where Rfleet_Protocol_grid_name__r.Name=:gridname];

    showgrid=true;

    return allcons;
}
Public List<RFLEET_Protocol_Line__c> getprotocolgrid1(){
    allcons = [Select Id,Rfleet_Model__c,Rfleet_Version__c,Rfleet_Discount__c  from RFLEET_Protocol_Line__c where Rfleet_Protocol_grid_name__r.Name=:gridname];
    showgrid1=true;
    return allcons;
}
Public List<RFLEET_Protocol_Line__c> getprotocolgrid2(){
    allcons = [Select Id,Rfleet_Model__c,Rfleet_Version__c,Rfleet_Option__c,Rfleet_Discount__c from RFLEET_Protocol_Line__c where Rfleet_Protocol_grid_name__r.Name=:gridname];
    showgrid2=true;
    return allcons;
}
Public List<RFLEET_Protocol_Line__c> getprotocolgrid3(){
    allcons = [Select Id,Rfleet_Model__c,Rfleet_Discount__c,Rfleet_Volume__c  from RFLEET_Protocol_Line__c where Rfleet_Protocol_grid_name__r.Name=:gridname];
    showgrid3=true;
    return allcons;
}
Public List<RFLEET_Protocol_Line__c> getprotocolgrid4(){
    allcons = [Select Id,Rfleet_Model__c,Rfleet_Version__c,Rfleet_Discount__c,Rfleet_Volume__c  from RFLEET_Protocol_Line__c where Rfleet_Protocol_grid_name__r.Name=:gridname];
    showgrid4=true;
    return allcons;
} 
Public List<RFLEET_Protocol_Line__c> getprotocolgrid5(){
    allcons = [Select Id,Rfleet_Model__c,Rfleet_Version__c,Rfleet_Option__c,Rfleet_Discount__c,Rfleet_Volume__c from RFLEET_Protocol_Line__c where Rfleet_Protocol_grid_name__r.Name=:gridname];
    showgrid5=true;
    return allcons;
}
Public List<RFLEET_Protocol_Line__c> getprotocolgrid6(){
    allcons = [Select Id,Rfleet_Model__c,Rfleet_Price__c,Rfleet_PricePercent__c,Rfleet_Volume__c from RFLEET_Protocol_Line__c where Rfleet_Protocol_grid_name__r.Name=:gridname];
    showgrid6=true;
    return allcons;
}


Public List<RFLEET_Protocol_Line__c> getprotocolgrid7(){
    allcons = [Select Id,Rfleet_Model__c,Rfleet_Version__c,Rfleet_Price__c,Rfleet_PricePercent__c,Rfleet_Volume__c  from RFLEET_Protocol_Line__c where Rfleet_Protocol_grid_name__r.Name=:gridname];
    showgrid7=true;
    return allcons;
}

Public List<RFLEET_Protocol_Line__c> getprotocolgrid8(){
    allcons = [Select Id,Rfleet_Model__c,Rfleet_Version__c,Rfleet_Option__c,Rfleet_Price__c,Rfleet_PricePercent__c,Rfleet_Volume__c  from RFLEET_Protocol_Line__c where Rfleet_Protocol_grid_name__r.Name=:gridname];
    showgrid8=true;
    return allcons;
}
    //selected values dispaly to text

Public void selectcon(){

   selcontactid = System.currentPagereference().getParameters().get('conid');
  if(gridtype=='Model - Discount %'){
        RFLEET_Protocol_Line__c con = [Select Rfleet_Model__c,Rfleet_Discount__c from RFLEET_Protocol_Line__c where id=:selcontactid ];
        System.debug('>>>>>>>'+con);
        selectcon =  new List<RFLEET_Protocol_Line__c>();
        selectcon.add(con);
    }else if(gridtype=='Model, Version - Discount %'){

        RFLEET_Protocol_Line__c con = [Select Rfleet_Model__c,Rfleet_Version__c,Rfleet_Discount__c from RFLEET_Protocol_Line__c where id=:selcontactid ];
        selectcon1 =  new List<RFLEET_Protocol_Line__c>();
        selectcon1.add(con);
        System.debug('selectcon >>>>>>'+selectcon1);

    }else if(gridtype=='Model, Version, Option - Discount %'){
        RFLEET_Protocol_Line__c con = [Select Rfleet_Model__c,Rfleet_Version__c,Rfleet_Option__c,Rfleet_Discount__c from RFLEET_Protocol_Line__c where id=:selcontactid ];
        selectcon2 =  new List<RFLEET_Protocol_Line__c>();
        selectcon2.add(con);
        System.debug('selectcon >>>>>>'+selectcon2);

    }else if(gridtype=='Model - Discount %, Volume'){
        RFLEET_Protocol_Line__c con = [Select Rfleet_Model__c,Rfleet_Discount__c,Rfleet_Volume__c from RFLEET_Protocol_Line__c where id=:selcontactid ];
        selectcon3 =  new List<RFLEET_Protocol_Line__c>();
        selectcon3.add(con);

    }else if(gridtype=='Model, Version - Discount %, Volume'){
        RFLEET_Protocol_Line__c con = [Select Rfleet_Model__c,Rfleet_Version__c,Rfleet_Discount__c,Rfleet_Volume__c from RFLEET_Protocol_Line__c where id=:selcontactid ];
        selectcon4 =  new List<RFLEET_Protocol_Line__c>();
        selectcon4.add(con);

    }else if(gridtype=='Model, Version, Option - Discount %, Volume'){
        RFLEET_Protocol_Line__c con = [Select Rfleet_Model__c,Rfleet_Version__c,Rfleet_Option__c,Rfleet_Discount__c,Rfleet_Volume__c from RFLEET_Protocol_Line__c where id=:selcontactid ];
        selectcon5 =  new List<RFLEET_Protocol_Line__c>();
        selectcon5.add(con);
    }
    else if(gridtype=='Model - Unique price, Unique price %,Volume'){
        RFLEET_Protocol_Line__c con = [Select Id,Rfleet_Model__c,Rfleet_Price__c,Rfleet_PricePercent__c,Rfleet_Volume__c from RFLEET_Protocol_Line__c where id=:selcontactid ];
        selectcon6 =  new List<RFLEET_Protocol_Line__c>();
        selectcon6.add(con);

    }else if(gridtype=='Model, Version - Unique price, Unique price %,Volume'){
        RFLEET_Protocol_Line__c con = [Select Id,Rfleet_Model__c,Rfleet_Version__c,Rfleet_Price__c,Rfleet_PricePercent__c,Rfleet_Volume__c  from RFLEET_Protocol_Line__c where id=:selcontactid ];
        selectcon7 =  new List<RFLEET_Protocol_Line__c>();
        selectcon7.add(con);
    }
    else if(gridtype=='Model, Version, Option - Unique price, Unique price %,Volume'){
        RFLEET_Protocol_Line__c con = [Select Id,Rfleet_Model__c,Rfleet_Version__c,Rfleet_Discount__c ,Rfleet_Option__c,Rfleet_Price__c,Rfleet_PricePercent__c,Rfleet_Volume__c  from RFLEET_Protocol_Line__c where id=:selcontactid ];
        selectcon8 =  new List<RFLEET_Protocol_Line__c>();
        selectcon8.add(con);
    }
}

Public List<RFLEET_Protocol_Line__c> getselectedContact(){showgrid=true;return selectcon;}
Public List<RFLEET_Protocol_Line__c> getselectedContact1(){showgrid1=true;return selectcon1;}
Public List<RFLEET_Protocol_Line__c> getselectedContact2(){showgrid2=true;return selectcon2;}
Public List<RFLEET_Protocol_Line__c> getselectedContact3() {showgrid3=true;return selectcon3;}
Public List<RFLEET_Protocol_Line__c> getselectedContact4() {showgrid4=true;return selectcon4;}
Public List<RFLEET_Protocol_Line__c> getselectedContact5() {showgrid5=true;return selectcon5;}
Public List<RFLEET_Protocol_Line__c> getselectedContact6() {showgrid6=true;return selectcon6;}
Public List<RFLEET_Protocol_Line__c> getselectedContact7() {showgrid7=true;return selectcon7;}
Public List<RFLEET_Protocol_Line__c> getselectedContact8() {showgrid8=true;return selectcon8;}

public void forloop(){
    pro= new list<RFLEET_Protocol_Line__c>();
    for(integer i=0 ; i<2 ;i++){
    RFLEET_Protocol_Line__c Pline= new RFLEET_Protocol_Line__c(Rfleet_Protocol_grid_name__c =gridid);
    pro.add(Pline);
    system.debug('>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>pro'+pro);}
} 

public PageReference insertNewItem() {
    insert pro;
    refreshPage=true;      
    return null;
}


Public void displayemptyCol(){showsave =true;forloop();}
Public void displayemptyCol1(){showsave1 =true;forloop();}
Public void displayemptyCol2(){showsave2 =true;forloop();}
Public void displayemptyCol3(){showsave3 =true;forloop();}
Public void displayemptyCol4(){showsave4 =true;forloop();}
Public void displayemptyCol5(){showsave5 =true;forloop();}
Public void displayemptyCol6(){showsave6 =true;forloop();}
Public void displayemptyCol7(){showsave7 =true;forloop();}
Public void displayemptyCol8(){showsave8 =true;forloop();}


public PageReference Selectedval1(){
    string  modelparam1= Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Model2');  
    string  versionparam1= Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Version2'); 
    string  Discountparam1= Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Discount2'); 
    system.debug('----->MD'+mdparamter);
    RFLEET_Protocol_Line__c proline = [Select Rfleet_Model__c,Rfleet_Version__c,Rfleet_Discount__c from RFLEET_Protocol_Line__c where id=:selcontactid ];      
    proline.Rfleet_Model__c= modelparam1;
    proline.Rfleet_Version__c= versionparam1;

    if(Discountparam1!=''){
    system.debug('-----withvalue');
    proline.Rfleet_Discount__c= Decimal.valueof(Discountparam1);
        }else{ 
     system.debug('-----without');
    proline.Rfleet_Discount__c=0;
     }

    update proline;
    refreshPage=true;  
    return null;
} 
public PageReference Selectedval2(){
    string  modelparam2= Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Model3');  
    string  versionparam2= Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Version3'); 
    string optionparam2= Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Option3'); 
    string  Discountparam2= Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Discount3'); 
    system.debug('----->MD'+mdparamter);
    RFLEET_Protocol_Line__c proline = [Select Rfleet_Model__c,Rfleet_Version__c,Rfleet_Option__c,Rfleet_Discount__c from RFLEET_Protocol_Line__c where id=:selcontactid ];      
    proline.Rfleet_Model__c= modelparam2;
    proline.Rfleet_Version__c= versionparam2;
    proline.Rfleet_Option__c= optionparam2;
    if(Discountparam2!=''){
    system.debug('-----withvalue');
    proline.Rfleet_Discount__c= Decimal.valueof(Discountparam2);
        }else{ 
     system.debug('-----without');
    proline.Rfleet_Discount__c=0;
     }
    refreshPage=true;  
    update proline;

    return null;
} 
public PageReference Selectedval3(){
    string  modelparam3= Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Model4');  
    string  Discountparam3= Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Discount4'); 
    string  Volumeparam3= Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Volume4'); 
    system.debug('----->MD'+mdparamter);
    RFLEET_Protocol_Line__c proline = [Select Rfleet_Model__c,Rfleet_Discount__c,Rfleet_Volume__c from RFLEET_Protocol_Line__c where id=:selcontactid ];      
    proline.Rfleet_Model__c= modelparam3;

    if(Discountparam3!=''){
    system.debug('-----withvalue');
    proline.Rfleet_Discount__c= Decimal.valueof(Discountparam3);
        }else{ 
     system.debug('-----without');
    proline.Rfleet_Discount__c=0;
     }
    if(Volumeparam3!=''){
    system.debug('-----withvalue');
    proline.Rfleet_Volume__c= Decimal.valueof(Volumeparam3);
        }else{ 
     system.debug('-----without');
    proline.Rfleet_Volume__c=0;
     }

        refreshPage=true;  
    update proline;
    return null;
} 
public PageReference Selectedval4(){
    string  modelparam4= Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Model5');
    string  versionparam4= Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Version5');  
    string  Discountparam4= Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Discount5'); 
    string  Volumeparam4= Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Volume5'); 
    system.debug('----->MD'+mdparamter);
    RFLEET_Protocol_Line__c proline = [Select Rfleet_Model__c,Rfleet_Version__c,Rfleet_Discount__c,Rfleet_Volume__c from RFLEET_Protocol_Line__c where id=:selcontactid ];      
    proline.Rfleet_Model__c= modelparam4;
    proline.Rfleet_Version__c= versionparam4; 
    if(Discountparam4!=''){
    system.debug('-----withvalue');
    proline.Rfleet_Discount__c= Decimal.valueof(Discountparam4);
        }else{ 
     system.debug('-----without');
    proline.Rfleet_Discount__c=0;
     }
     if(Volumeparam4!=''){
    system.debug('-----withvalue');
    proline.Rfleet_Volume__c= Decimal.valueof(Volumeparam4);
        }else{ 
     system.debug('-----without');
    proline.Rfleet_Volume__c=0;
     }


           refreshPage=true;  
    update proline;
    return null;
} 
public PageReference Selectedval5(){
    string  modelparam5= Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Model6');
    string  versionparam5= Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Version6');  
    string  optionparam5= Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Option6');
    string  Discountparam5= Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Discount6'); 
    string  Volumeparam5= Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Volume6'); 
    system.debug('----->MD'+mdparamter);
    RFLEET_Protocol_Line__c proline = [Select Rfleet_Model__c,Rfleet_Version__c,Rfleet_Option__c,Rfleet_Discount__c,Rfleet_Volume__c from RFLEET_Protocol_Line__c where id=:selcontactid ];      
    proline.Rfleet_Model__c= modelparam5;
    proline.Rfleet_Version__c= versionparam5;
    proline.Rfleet_Option__c= optionparam5; 
    if(Discountparam5!=''){
    system.debug('-----withvalue');
    proline.Rfleet_Discount__c= Decimal.valueof(Discountparam5);
        }else{ 
     system.debug('-----without');
    proline.Rfleet_Discount__c=0;
     }
    if(Volumeparam5!=''){
    system.debug('-----withvalue');
    proline.Rfleet_Volume__c= Decimal.valueof(Volumeparam5);
        }else{ 
     system.debug('-----without');
    proline.Rfleet_Volume__c=0;
     }

    refreshPage=true;  
    update proline;
    return null;
} 

public PageReference Selectedval6(){
    string  modelparam6= Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Model7');
    string  Priceparam6= Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Price7');  
    string  Pricepercentparam6= Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('PricePercent7');
    string  Volumeparam6= Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Volume7'); 
    system.debug('----->MD'+mdparamter);
    RFLEET_Protocol_Line__c proline = [Select Rfleet_Model__c,Rfleet_Price__c,Rfleet_PricePercent__c,Rfleet_Volume__c from RFLEET_Protocol_Line__c where id=:selcontactid ];      
    proline.Rfleet_Model__c= modelparam6;
    if(Priceparam6!=''){
    system.debug('-----withvalue');
    proline.Rfleet_Price__c= Decimal.valueof(Priceparam6);
        }else{ 
     system.debug('-----without');
    proline.Rfleet_Price__c=0;
     }

     if(Pricepercentparam6!=''){
    system.debug('-----withvalue');
    proline.Rfleet_PricePercent__c= Decimal.valueof(Pricepercentparam6);
        }else{ 
     system.debug('-----without');
    proline.Rfleet_PricePercent__c=0;
     }

if(Volumeparam6!=''){
    system.debug('-----withvalue');
    proline.Rfleet_Volume__c= Decimal.valueof(Volumeparam6);}
    else{ 
     system.debug('-----without');
    proline.Rfleet_Volume__c=0;
     }

   update proline;
    refreshPage=true;  
    return null;
} 

public PageReference Selectedval7(){
    string  modelparam7= Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Model8');
    string  Versionparam7= Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Version8');  
    string  Priceparam7= Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Price8');  
    string  Pricepercentparam7= Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('PricePercent8');
    string  Volumeparam7= Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Volume8'); 
    system.debug('----->MD'+mdparamter);
    RFLEET_Protocol_Line__c proline = [Select Rfleet_Model__c,Rfleet_Version__c,Rfleet_Price__c,Rfleet_PricePercent__c,Rfleet_Volume__c from RFLEET_Protocol_Line__c where id=:selcontactid ];      
    proline.Rfleet_Model__c= modelparam7;
    proline.Rfleet_Version__c= Versionparam7;

    if(Priceparam7!=''){
    system.debug('-----withvalue');
   proline.Rfleet_Price__c= Decimal.valueof(Priceparam7);

        }else{ 
     system.debug('-----without');
    proline.Rfleet_Price__c=0;
     }

        if(Pricepercentparam7!=''){
    system.debug('-----withvalue');
     proline.Rfleet_PricePercent__c= Decimal.valueof(Pricepercentparam7);
        }else{ 
     system.debug('-----without');
    proline.Rfleet_PricePercent__c=0;
     }


    if(Volumeparam7!=''){
    system.debug('-----withvalue');
    proline.Rfleet_Volume__c= Decimal.valueof(Volumeparam7);    }
    else{ 
     system.debug('-----without');
    proline.Rfleet_Volume__c=0;
     }


    update proline;
    refreshPage=true;  
    return null;
} 

public PageReference Selectedval8(){
    string  modelparam8= Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Model9');
    string  Versionparam8= Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Version9');
    string  optionparam8= Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Option9');
    string  Priceparam8= Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Price9');  
    string  Pricepercentparam8= Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('PricePercent9');
    string  Volumeparam8= Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Volume9'); 
    system.debug('----->MD'+mdparamter);
    RFLEET_Protocol_Line__c proline = [Select Rfleet_Model__c,Rfleet_Version__c,Rfleet_Option__c,Rfleet_Price__c,Rfleet_PricePercent__c,Rfleet_Volume__c from RFLEET_Protocol_Line__c where id=:selcontactid ];      
    system.debug('----->proline:' +proline );
    proline.Rfleet_Model__c= modelparam8;
    proline.Rfleet_Version__c= Versionparam8;
    proline.Rfleet_Option__c= optionparam8;
    if(Priceparam8!=''){
    system.debug('-----withvalue');
    proline.Rfleet_Price__c= Decimal.valueof(Priceparam8);
        }else{ 
     system.debug('-----without');
    proline.Rfleet_Price__c=0;
     }

    if(Pricepercentparam8!=''){
    system.debug('-----withvalue');
      proline.Rfleet_PricePercent__c= Decimal.valueof(Pricepercentparam8);
        }else{ 
     system.debug('-----without');
    proline.Rfleet_PricePercent__c=0;
     }

     if(Volumeparam8!=''){
    system.debug('-----withvalue');
   proline.Rfleet_Volume__c= Decimal.valueof(Volumeparam8);    }
    else{ 
     system.debug('-----without');
    proline.Rfleet_Volume__c=0;
     }


    update proline;
    refreshPage=true;  
    return null;
}    

}
```

Test class:

```
@isTest
public class RFLEET_ProtocolDynamicGrid_Test {

    static testMethod void testgrid(){
    Test.StartTest();
     //grid = [select id,Name,Rfleet_Type_of_Grid__c from RFLEET_Protocol_Grid__c limit 1];
    RFLEET_Protocol_Grid__c din = new RFLEET_Protocol_Grid__c(Name='sand');
    insert din;
    din.Name = 'sanc';
    update din;
     system.debug('din.id'+din.id);   

     Account Acc= New Account(Name='A1',Montant__c=1.4);
    insert Acc;

    RFLEET_Protocol__c Rpro=new RFLEET_Protocol__c(Name='Aggre',Rfleet_Agreement_Client__c=Acc.id,Rfleet_Status__c='Actif',Rfleet_Billing_Type__c='Dossier');
    insert Rpro;

    RFLEET_Protocol_Grid__c pg=new RFLEET_Protocol_Grid__c(Name='t1',Rfleet_Type_of_Grid__c='Model - Discount %',Rfleet_Type_of_Sales__c='VD',Rfleet_Protocol__c=Rpro.id);
   insert pg;



    RFLEET_Protocol_Line__c  record = new RFLEET_Protocol_Line__c(Rfleet_Model__c='model', Rfleet_Version__c='test',Rfleet_Discount__c=1.2,Rfleet_Option__c='test',Rfleet_Volume__c=1,Rfleet_Price__c=12,Rfleet_Protocol_grid_name__c=pg.id);
    insert record;

     ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('id',din.id);
     ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.standardController(din);
     RFLEET_ProtocolDynamicGrid  rp = new RFLEET_ProtocolDynamicGrid(sc);
     string  mdparamter;
     string  Discountparam;

      //rp.Selectedval();
     //rp.Delrecords();
     rp.getprotocolgrid1();
     rp.getprotocolgrid2();
     rp.getprotocolgrid3();
     rp.getprotocolgrid4();
     rp.getprotocolgrid5();
     rp.getprotocolgrid6();
     rp.getprotocolgrid7();
     rp.getprotocolgrid8();
     rp.selectcon();
     rp.getselectedContact();
     rp.getselectedContact1();
     rp.getselectedContact2();
     rp.getselectedContact3();
     rp.getselectedContact4();
     rp.getselectedContact5();
     rp.getselectedContact6();
     rp.getselectedContact7();
     rp.getselectedContact8();
     rp.forloop();
     rp.displayemptyCol();
     rp.displayemptyCol1();
     rp.displayemptyCol2();
     rp.displayemptyCol3();
     rp.displayemptyCol4();
     rp.displayemptyCol5();
     rp.displayemptyCol6();
     rp.displayemptyCol7();
     rp.displayemptyCol8();
     //rp.Selectedval1();
     //rp.Selectedval2();
     //rp.Selectedval3();
     //rp.Selectedval4();
     //rp.Selectedval5();
     //rp.Selectedval6();
     //rp.Selectedval7();
     //rp.Selectedval8();
    }



     //rp.Selectedval();





    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SF.SE user3577682. Please don't repost the same question ore than once. You'll find that people will be more willing to spend time helping you with these kinds of problems if you tell them which lines of code aren't covered by your test class (hint: knowing the line number isn't helpful since we can't tell the number when viewing it here, so mark you code sections).

Answer (score 2):

When you have an if-else condition you need two test methods. One that has data that will pass the positive condition and another with data that will fail. You need sufficient sets of data and test methods to make it through every combination of if-else conditions in your code in order to obtain complete coverage.